# Find k with the given vectors and if $\Vert ku + v\Vert = 13$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

> Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ have the Euclidean inner product and $u=(1,1,-1)$ and $v=(6,7,-15)$.
>   Find k if $\Vert ku + v\Vert = 13$

So what I did was this:
$ \Vert ku + v\Vert^2 = \langle ku+v, ku + v\rangle = 13^2\\
\quad\quad\ \ 169=\langle ku,ku \rangle + 2\langle ku,v \rangle + \langle v,v \rangle \\
\quad\quad\ \ 169=k^2(1+1+1) + 2k(6+7+15) + (36+49+225) \\
\quad\quad\ \ 169=3k^2 + 56k + 310 \\
\quad\quad\ \ 0 = 3k^2 + 56k +141$

Then I just worked it out with a quadratic formula which came to.
15.49 or 3.17. I'm thinking this is not correct and there is no answer in the book. Does anybody have any ideas with this one?

Comment: Looks okay to me..

Comment: Thanks for checking @nemo

Comment: You totally failed to solve the quadratic equation! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k (1,1,-1)+(6,7,-15)=(6 + k, 7 + k, -15 - k)$

$(6+k)^2+(7+k)^2+(-15-k)^2=169$

$3 k^2+56 k+141=0$

$k=-\dfrac{47}{3},\;k=-3$

Hope this helps

Comment: That is helpful @Raffaele. However, I would like to know how you found the roots. I am probably a little scratchy on factorising. I wouldn't mind knowing the technique you used to find the roots of such an equation. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks @Rafaelle. I googled how to do it by factorising. Cheers.